# Laravel validation get value from a column and compare it to another table column

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, lumen, laravel-validation

I have the following tables:

```
- companies
- users
- departments
- services
```

We have the following structure:

`A user belongs to a company`
`A company has many departments`
`One department has multiple services.`

The problem is that I want to validate the service department that has a specific `company_id` flag using only the service ID.

Database:

company

```
| id | name         |
| 1  | Company 1    |
| 2  | Company 2    |
```

user

```
| id | name         | company_id |
| 1  | User 1       | 1          |
```

departments

```
| id | name         | company_id |
| 1  | Department 1 | 1          |
| 2  | Department 2 | 2          |
```

services

```
| id | name      | departments_id |
| 1  | Service 1 | 1              |
| 2  | Service 2 | 2              |
```

The endpoints looks like this:

Looged in user belongs to `Company 1`

```
$app->delete('/{id}', ['uses' => 'ServicesController@deleteService']);
```

Delete service method

```
public function deleteService($id, Request $request)
{
    $request['id'] = $id;
    $this->validate($request, [
        'id' => 'required|exists:services,id',
    ]);

    $result = Service::deleteService($id, $this->user->company_id);
    return response()->json($result);
}
```

The user of `Company 1` should not be able to delete the `Service 2`.
How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `policies` in Laravel, check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#creating-policies)

it will be something like this

```
    $request['id'] = $id;
$this->validate($request, [
    'id' => 'required|exists:services,id',
    ]);


$this->authorize('delete', $id); // will check if user can delete the company as the needed logic. 

$result = Service::deleteService($id, $this->user->company_id);
return response()->json($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The most overseeable way would be to write a [custom validator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#custom-validation-rules)